# Escaping text with SASS?

Tags: sass

I'm running into an issue of which I think is due to the way SASS (SCSS in my case) compiles. I'm trying to get this code to compile: (it's a very hacky way to simulate `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements in IE6/7)

```
.x-tool-collapse-top {
  *zoom: expression( 
    this.runtimeStyle.zoom="1",
    this.appendChild( document.createElement("small") ).className="after",
    this.insertBefore( document.createElement("small"), this.firstChild ).className="before"
  );
}

.x-tool-collapse-top .after,
.x-tool-collapse-top:after {
  @include extjsimagereplace;
  content: '\e6be';
  *zoom: expression(this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = '1', this.innerHTML = '&#xe6be;');
}
```

But it's choking. It's likely due to the `,` and `(` which aren't valid, but I'm not finding anything to just say *SASS: just leave this alone and don't try and compile it*.

Comment: Is the expected output exactly what you have typed in the SCSS?

Comment: Are you getting a compilation failure (and which error?) or just "wrong" output?